# How to validate my form in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate the full name part of my form, the requirements are:

1. Only alphabet, spaces between words and "-" are valid.
2. Minimum of 3 characters and max of 35.

My HTML code is as follows:

```js
function test(myForm) 
{         
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(regex.test(myForm.full_name.value) == false) {
        alert("Name must be in alphabets only");
        myForm.full_name.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Full Name: </b>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" required/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex, which doesn’t allow space or `-` characters at the start or end of the string:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z- ]{1,33}[a-zA-Z]$/
```

Comment: This would allow names that are too long, because the middle character class can be repeated any number of times before the `{1,35}` starts counting. Instead you should move `{1,35}` to the middle character class, change the maximum repetition to `33`, and remove the unnecessary parentheses around the regex: `/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z- ]{1,33}[a-zA-Z]$/`

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do the work for you `/(^[a-zA-Z -]{3,35}$)/`
Explanation:
      `[a-zA-z -]` --  Any character space or `-`
      `{3,35}`  -- repeat between 3 to 35 times

Example:

```js
    function test(name) {         
       var regex = /(^[a-zA-Z -]{3,35}$)/
       return regex.test(name)
    }

console.log(test('valid-name'))
console.log(test('valid Name'))
console.log(test('valid'))
console.log(test('in'))
console.log(test('invalid~name'))
console.log(test('invalidname invalidname invalidname invalidname'))
```